# Centos 7 Withe Sendmail & Dovecot. Auth Broken

Tags: centos, dovecot, sendmail

I have tried many different configuration options but using either Outlook or Thunderbird on macOS I cannot send through a server migrated to a new machine.  I have done the Dovecot troubleshooting from:
https://wiki2.dovecot.org/TestInstallation
and it passed.

IRRC,  when sending from a client one is actually talking to Sendmail not Dovecot, is that right?   BTW, receiving works fine,  just cannot send.

Using Auth with pam.  Procmail with Spamassassin is there and working.

Is sasl needed?

I would appreciate any help, I have configured this several times previously over some years and always managed to make it work.

Robert

Comment: BTW,  it does not send if I turn off encryption and use port 25.  Outlook has Auth error.  Receive works with port 143 and Starttls.

Comment: started saslauthd and I can send with SSL off but not with it on.  Get  STARTTLS=server: 7706:error:140BA0C3:SSL routines:SSL_new:null ssl ctx:ssl_lib.c:299:  in the maillog.

Comment: Created new cert and SSL is working but STARTTLS is not in Thunderbird.

Comment: Recreated the account serveral times in Thunderbird and it is working now.

Comment: The answer here was saslauthd needs to be working and I recreated sendmail.pem

Answer (score 0):

The answer here was saslauthd needs to be working and I recreated sendmail.pem